# How can I authenticate with Email and Google account in Firebase with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I have been searching and I can´t find information that helps me, somebody know something about this?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has personally gone through this same issue, I admit information on how to do this is scarce. This was a VERY helpful page for me: https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/26/firebase-authentication-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I'll be happy to try to answer any other questions you may have with Firebase integration in Xamarin, as I too felt lost in the woods as I was doing it with my app.